# Hamburger Icon/Android Iconography Guidelines

Tags: icons, android, menu

I have the Hamburger/Menu icon in the top left corner of the app in the Action Bar. I know that the normal action bar items (which are on the right) have specific rules about size and opacity (like 60 or 80% opacity, etc). Do those same rules apply to the hamburger icon on the right?

Answer (score 2):

In the **[Iconography > Action Bar section](https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)** of Android Design Guidelines you can find this:

[image]

In the **same section** you can download the **"Action Bar Icon Pack"**.
It contains the "Navigation Drawer Indicator" icon files (i.e., the **hamburger icon**).
I think we can therefore assume the guidelines apply to that icon, too.